# appframework UI $.ui.autoLaunch = false disables loadpanel event

Tags: events, appframework

as in title. If I set $.ui.autoLaunch to false (to get splashscreen) and fire $.ui.launch(); after few seconds, loadpanel event is not being fired when I switch between views. Anyone faced that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using an older version of [appframework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/)?, here is a working example of `loadpanel` event firing with `$.ui.autoLaunch = false`:

http://jsbin.com/rigit/1/edit

This example is using latest 2.1 version of [Intel appframework](https://github.com/01org/appframework).